# Rails: reshape params to desired structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some params that I need to reshape?

I've got an old database I'm trying to build a new app on top of to access and do CRUD operations on.

I simply need to make this structure...

```
{
"volunteer_shift_attributes"=><ActionController::Parameters{
    "volunteer_task_type_id"=>"41", 
    "roster_id"=>"7",
    "program_id"=>"9",
    "set_description"=>"ddddddddddd"
} permitted: true>, 
"set_date"=>"2021-01-14", 
"contact_id"=>"166574", 
"closed"=>"0", 
"start_time(4i)"=>"14", 
"start_time(5i)"=>"00", 
"end_time(4i)"=>"15", 
"end_time(5i)"=>"00",
"notes"=>"nnnnnnnnnnnnn",
}
```

have this structure...

```
{
"volunteer_shift_attributes"=>{
    "volunteer_task_type_id"=>"41", 
    "roster_id"=>"7", 
    "program_id"=>"9", 
    "set_description"=>"ddddddddddd"
}, 
"set_date"=>"2021-01-15",  
"contact_id"=>"166574", 
"closed"=>"0", 
"start_time(4i)"=>"14", 
"start_time(5i)"=>"00", 
"end_time(4i)"=>"15", 
"end_time(5i)"=>"00", 
"notes"=>"aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
}
```

NOTE: this is called inside a controller method like so

```
def create_shift
...
   a.attributes = (params["assignment"])
...
end
```

I need to rebuild this param by hand.

Comment: You can call `.to_h` to convert an ActionController::Parameters to a simple hash. Though ActiveRecord should handle a Parameters object just fine.

Comment: @arieljuod so you're saying params["assignment"].to_h would straighten that out?

Comment: @Eyeslandic added UPDATE to post. hope this additional info answers question.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That looks like a custom error message, so presumably there's something in the Volunteer model or elsewhere that defines it. If you can locate where the error is defined, you can see what condition is causing it. (Also, nowhere in your params is there a key "assignment" so it's no surprise that fails.)

Comment: You seem to have undone your update and removed the information from the question again. Can you let us know why you've done this?

Comment: @arieljuod thank you for response....this was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

It's not clear exactly why you need to do this - they're just params and you're not looking to change the structure, exactly. But it looks like it could be a case for strong params. Define a private method:

```rb
def volunteer_shift_params
  params.require(:volunteer_shift_attributes)
        .permit(:volunteer_task_type_id, 
                :roster_id, 
                :program_id, 
                :set_description)
end
```

Then, you should be able to do this, as you asked:

```rb
a.attributes = volunteer_shift_params
```

Comment: Strong params have been turned off. I just need to change the params string from one structure to the other as indicated.

Comment: The explanation for disabling strong params in your edit to the question doesn't make sense to me. Strong params only deal with the way the form communicates with your Rails 5 app, not the database. And they're a great way to make your application safer.